# Gradle 6.4, Kotlin and JPMS

Tags: kotlin, gradle, java-platform-module-system

So, 6.4 is (finally) out and has [JPMS support](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/890#issuecomment-603289940)

Eager to give it a try, I started to modify one project of ours in order to play with it.

jjohannes has a (kotlin) example on one of his [repo](https://github.com/jjohannes/gradle-jpms-experiments/blob/master/module-kotlin/build.gradle.kts)

I tried to copy/paste what mattered into our project [here](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/kotlin-unsigned/blob/jpms/build.gradle.kts)

But unfortunately I didn't succeded.

Whenever I try to run, I always get:

> C:\Users\elect\IdeaProjects\kotlin-unsigned\src\main\java\module-info.java:4: error: module not found: kotlin.stdlib.jdk8
>       requires kotlin.stdlib.jdk8;

Referring to the `module-info.java`:

```java
module com.github.kotlin_graphics.kotlin_unsigned {

//    requires kotlin.stdlib;
    requires kotlin.stdlib.jdk8; // error

    exports unsigned;
}
```

`stdlib` or `stdlib-jdk8` doesn't change much

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your repo.

You will need these fixes.

- Added `java` plugin.

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    java
}

java {
    modularity.inferModulePath.set(true)
}
```

- Use `kotlin("stdlib")` in all 3 places (2 in build.gradle.kts and 1 in module-info.java).

```
dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    ...
    components { withModule<ModularKotlinRule>(kotlin("stdlib")) }
}
```

```
module com.github.kotlin_graphics.kotlin_unsigned {

    requires kotlin.stdlib;
//    requires kotlin.stdlib.jdk8;

    exports unsigned;
}
```

For `kotlin("stdlib-jdk8")`, you need to add it alongside `kotlin("stdlib")`

```
dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    ...
    components { withModule<ModularKotlinRule>(kotlin("stdlib")) }
    components { withModule<ModularKotlinRule>(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8")) }
}
```

Then, your `module-info.java` can be

```
module com.github.kotlin_graphics.kotlin_unsigned {

//    requires kotlin.stdlib;
    requires kotlin.stdlib.jdk8;

    exports unsigned;
}
```

`./gradlew build` built successfully for me.
I also add to add missing test dependency:

```
testImplementation("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:$kotlintest_version")
```

UPDATE: Listed for both `stdlib` and `stdlb-jdk8`

Comment: Thanks, it finally works. I also tried `stdlib-jdk8` though and it keeps saying `e: Module kotlin.stdlib cannot be found in the module graph`. Have you succedeed with it?

Comment: I made the correction to the answer.  Listed for both `stdlib` and `stdlb-jdk8`

Comment: It works. Is this safe though? Isn't there gonna be problems importing them both this way? (Any interference or whatever)

Comment: No, it should not interfere.  `stdlib-jdk8` internally uses `stdlib`.  In normal cases, you do not have to add `stdlib` since it is transitively available via `stdlib-jdk8`.  You can also experiment by adding it compiletimeonly and see if it works at runtime.  
`compileOnly(kotlin("stdlib"))`

For your library, I would recommend to use `stdlib` which makes the library usable on older versions of Java for Android.